# Identity Server 4 Refresh Token Storage

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, jwt, identityserver4, refresh-token

I need to store random generated refresh token at server side. For example if user have an active refresh token, then server do not allow this user to generate another refresh token. Server needs to return existing refresh token to user. I think that if i am store the refresh tokens when they create first time on server side, then i can check all token request on server. Is there a possible way ?

Comment: Refresh tokens are already persisted so you could retire some custom logic to always return the same one but that’d be somewhat non-standard. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: our clients sometimes use same username/password for authentication and we can not follow their transactions with their token information. We want to specify ip based refresh tokens. We send ip addresses on http request header and store them on sql server at the response side but we can not catch refresh token information on identity server's persisted side.

Comment: Check out IPersistedGrantStore in IdentityServer4 and see if you can work within its confines. If not you may need to create a custom grant with its own backing store.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain to your clients that single sign-on doesn't mean that multiple users use the same account.  A user account is personal and can't be shared. You should add this in the terms that should be accepted before using an account. Instead of adding a dimension to IdentityServer, prevent users from sharing accounts. It's far more easier to add an additional account and use the default IdentityServer.

Comment: I use IPersistedGrantStore yet. Maybe custom PersistedGrant structure solve my problem i try it soon!

Comment: Finally, i found solution friends. I used IPersistedGrantStore and OperationalStore features at same time.IPersistedGrantStore provides to store and manage all token sessions and OperationalStore support them, it present to multiple database option to store and manage these records. I select Ms-sql and my server working very well. thanks for your valuable comments..